# Get Current Caret Position Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm building a desktop mac app that runs in the background. Right now when a user pushes a keyboard shortcut a window appears in the top right with several options of what to insert at the Current Caret position.

All this works fine, but I think the App would be better if I could make this option box appear above the caret. How do you get the current caret position into a set of variables I can use when showing my window?

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Not sure where to start

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @centree, did you find any solution to display a window above caret position (in another app) ?

Comment: It'll be difficult. Here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610607/how-to-find-the-blinking-cursor-location-of-any-active-application

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
NSRange selection = [textView selectedRange];
NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
NSTextContainer* textContainer = [textView textContainer];
NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRageForCharacterRange:selection actualCharacterRange:nil];
NSRect boundingRect = [layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:textContainer];
```

The boundingRect is in textContainer coords, so you'll then have to convert them to something more useful to you.  `[textView textContainerOrigin]` will be useful here.

Comment: Will this work even if my app is in the background and another app like text edit is in the foreground ?

Comment: Ah, you want to get the caret position for someone else's app? No, this would only do it for a textview in your own app. I don't know how to do it for another app.

Comment: Yeah trying to trigger a window to appear above it when someone uses our keyboard shortcut. Thanks anyway