# How to find the blinking cursor location of any active application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm developing an app for Mac OS and I want to find the location of text cursor (caret navigation) of current application? 
So far i have make it ask for accessibility permission and I can monitor keyEvents too, but how do I find blinking cursor location?

(I'm not looking for mouse cursor location, I want [text cursor / caret navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation))

Comment: 'Blinking cursor'? You mean the element that has firstResponder (NSTextField f.e.?)

Comment: @JasperPol  when you type in computer, there's a small vertical line that blinks, to show where u are typing. This is seen almost anywhere typing is involved.

Comment: Yeah, its called firstResponder

Answer (score 9):

You're going to need to use the Accessibility APIs to do this.
It's a lot of ugly ugly code and it may not always work, depending on the view hierarchies and degrees of accessibility support in those apps' views.
Non-Cocoa apps will likely be problematic and just not work.
Views that are using WebKit for rendering also present the entire html accessibility challenge! :)

I got this snippet from Bogdan Popescu who makes Dash.
Do not copy and paste this code directly. 
Study it, see what the API docs say about each function and type, and build something slowly from this.
It takes a lot of time to understand the AX APIs and use them. It takes even longer to use them well in generic ways.
It is Core Foundation style C and a great deal different than what you might be used to in straight Cocoa Objective-C.

```
CFTypeRef system = nil;
system = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
CFTypeRef application = nil;
CFTypeRef focusedElement = nil;
CFRange cfrange;
AXValueRef rangeValue = nil;
// Find the currently focused application
if(AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(system, kAXFocusedApplicationAttribute, &application) == kAXErrorSuccess)
{
    // Find the currently focused UI Element
    if(AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(application, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, &focusedElement) == kAXErrorSuccess)
    {
        // Get the range attribute of the selected text (i.e. the cursor position)
        if(AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&rangeValue) == kAXErrorSuccess)
        {
            // Get the actual range from the range attribute
            if(AXValueGetValue(rangeValue, kAXValueCFRangeType, (void *)&cfrange))
            {
                CFTypeRef bounds = nil;
                textRect = NSZeroRect;
                if(AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(focusedElement, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute, rangeValue, (CFTypeRef *)&bounds) == kAXErrorSuccess)
                {
                    CGRect screenRect;
                    AXValueGetValue(bounds, kAXValueCGRectType, &screenRect);
                    if(bounds)
                    {
                        textRect = [DHAbbreviationManager cocoaRectFromCarbonScreenRect:screenRect];
                        CFRelease(bounds);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(rangeValue)
            {
                CFRelease(rangeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    if(focusedElement)
    {
        CFRelease(focusedElement);
    }
}
if(application)
{
    CFRelease(application);
}
if(system)
{
    CFRelease(system);
}
```

Convert the AX points from Carbon to Cocoa Screen points.

```
+ (NSPoint)cocoaScreenPointFromCarbonScreenPoint:(NSPoint)carbonPoint
{
   return NSMakePoint(carbonPoint.x, [[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame].size.height - carbonPoint.y);
}
```

Study these bits.

You'll also want to delve into the **Accessibility Inspector app** that ships with Xcode as well as the similar sample code from Apple called **UIElementInspector**

Comment: Thanks a lot! i will study this and get back to you. have a nice day!

Comment: can you please explain where to find "DHAbbreviationManager cocoaRectFromCarbonScreenRect:"

Comment: That would be just the name of the class the originator put all this inside of. The second part is a convenience function he wrote to convert point systems.

Comment: So if there is a cursor it can have a location and length of zero, meaning no selection but a position in the string.

Comment: I've tried and it is worked with the native app (calendar, contacts, etc) but not other app built with Electron or ReactNative like Skype, Slack. Any body know how to get the cursor in those app?

Comment: It may depend on the Electron app, but it's all web stuff all the way down if you're in a web view. What that means is, if the web content itself has the proper semantic richness (or explicit ARIA attributes in the tags) to express what the macOS native elements express, it will probably just work. But if not, you get to play JavaScript / DOM  script dances. Remember, this is based on accessibility APIs, and if web content is not accessible, it won't likely help.